# Rsyslog regex extract trigrams from hostname

Tags: regex, posix, rsyslog, lookbehind

I have difficulties to find a way to extract a trigram from the `%hostname%` var in `rsyslog conf` to create a path with POSIX regex.

My logic was to take the 3 characters before the first digit of the hostname.

Any ideas to have this result from only one regex ? I tried to find solutions on forum/website but none works for my case. i know that positioning lookbehind and lookforward does not work with POSIX

Hope you can help me with this one.

thx !

exemple: `zyabc01da` and need to keep the `abc` trigrams to make something like this `/LOGS/abc/hostname/*.logs`

i tried regex like this one `(.{3}[\d])` or `(.{3}[\D])`, but i can't get rid of the first digit and the only solution i have is to make a second regex `([\D]+)`

Comment: Posix does not have lookaheads which would solve this easily.  Not knowing the exact tool you are using, do you have access to a regexp_replace function?  You could then use capture group 1 like `^.*?(.{3})\d+.*$` and then replace with \1.

Comment: Perhaps use the capture group only and match the digit outside of it `([^\d[:space:]]{3})\d` https://regex101.com/r/eZVuA7/1

Comment: dunno how to get this with rsyslog conf file but it only works that way %hostname:R,ERE,1,DFLT:(^.*?(.{3})\\d+.*$)--end%
but it seems to work on their regex checker https://www.rsyslog.com/regex/ but not on my rsyslog server, i just get a "no match" result